# Firebase authentication and database linking

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

In android studio 3.1.3, for linking firebase auth "**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'**" and
for linking firebase database "**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'**"   are the default dependencies provided in app level gradle.

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'** is the dependency added

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.arsalan.adda"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com/"
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
  implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in project level gradle.

I'm usung gradle 3.1.2

The different levels of firebase are causing me errors. Please provide a common level of firebase version that can be used with my gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

just update them with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

and your google gms update with

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to see the latest Firebase SDK versions.  I think it is a reasonable assumption to make that the latest ones will work together.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this problem's unique to Linux.. but anyway finally I had to downgrade the dependencies to get them working..

Module app (dependencies)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
```

Project

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```